# SQL Left-Join - Get value If both values are Not null in TableB or Row missing in TableB

Tags: sql, sql-server

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d1cf0/6

```
TABLE HEADER 
(
     [HeaderID] VARCHAR(3), 
     [description] VARCHAR(50),
      [ProcessStatus] bit 
);

TABLE DETAILS
(
    [HeaderID] VARCHAR(3), 
    [DETAIL_VALUE_1] VARCHAR(50),
    [DETAIL_VALUE_2] VARCHAR(50)
);

SELECT DISTINCT 
    H.HEADERID 
FROM 
    HEADER H 
LEFT JOIN
    DETAILS D ON H.HeaderID = D.HeaderID 
              AND (D.DETAIL_VALUE_1 IS NOT NULL AND 
                   D.DETAIL_VALUE_2 IS NOT NULL)
WHERE H.ProcessStatus = 0
```

Based on the sample data provided in SQL Fiddle, the above query returns `1,2,3..`

I need the query to return only `2,3` as the header 1 has one of the records where `DETAIL_VALUE_1` is not null but `DETAIL_VALUE_2` is null.

These tables might have million+ records.
Header table is the anchor..i.e the Header table will have a flag 'ProcessStatus' to indicate which records have already been processed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good job on providing a SQL Fiddle with sample data. Impressive for your first post.

Comment: @scsimon I agree 100%. I wish even 2% of the people made their questions so clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want to find rows where the "bad condition" doesn't exist...kinda double negative, perhaps?

```
select 
  H.HEADERID 
from
  HEADER H 
where 
  not exists 
  ( 
    select * 
    from 
      Details D 
    where
      H.HeaderID= D.HeaderID 
      and 
      (
        D.DETAIL_VALUE_1 IS NULL 
        or
        D.DETAIL_VALUE_2 IS NULL
      )
    )
```

Comment: This seems like the most sensible solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT IN`

```
SELECT H.HEADERID 
FROM HEADER H 
WHERE HeaderID not in (select d.HeaderID from DETAILS d where (DETAIL_VALUE_1 is null or DETAIL_VALUE_2 is null))
```

Notice I didn't `JOIN` to the table, and I removed the `DISTINCT` since neither were needed.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d1cf0/15/0

If you plan to use columns from `DETAILS` you can still join to it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT H.HEADERID 
FROM HEADER H 
LEFT JOIN DETAILS D on
D.HeaderID = H.HeaderID
WHERE H.HeaderID not in (select d.HeaderID from DETAILS d where (DETAIL_VALUE_1 is null or DETAIL_VALUE_2 is null))
```

Comment: Thanks scsimon, but Header.HeaderID is the starting point for identifying which records to process and also the Details table might have 1 to 3 million rows which might have already been processed and the flag that indicates that they are processed is in the Header table.

Comment: This is an excellent answer based on the question. Do you have any more rules that you have not yet shared? Might be a good idea to share ALL the details. For the issue at hand can't you just add another where predicate to this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @G8371 but I added an edited answer using your approach if it helps.

Comment: @SeanLange, I assumed naming of tables Header/Details  or Parent/Child will indicate that the header or parent record is the anchor. I will update the question with this info.

Comment: thanks @scsimon, I will test the performance of query on actual data but looks like the statement "not in (select d.HeaderID from DETAILS d where (DETAIL_VALUE_1 is null or DETAIL_VALUE_2 is null))" will run on the entire "DETAILS " table.

Comment: Yes but not how you think I suspect

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by utilising the fact that `COUNT` only counts non-null values, and checking that the count of `HeaderID` values in `DETAILS` is the same as the count of `DETAIL_VALUE_1` and `DETAIL_VALUE_2` values. This query also works where there are no rows in `DETAILS` because all of the `COUNT` values are 0.

```
SELECT H.HeaderID
FROM HEADER H 
LEFT JOIN DETAILS D ON H.HeaderID= D.HeaderID
GROUP BY H.HeaderID
HAVING COUNT(D.HeaderId) = COUNT(D.DETAIL_VALUE_1) AND COUNT(D.HeaderID) = COUNT(D.DETAIL_VALUE_2)
```

Output:

```
HEADERID
2
3
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d1cf0/32)